# ValueAnimator changing other non-required values

Tags: android, kotlin, android-animation

This is something weird and unexpected that is happening. While creating a custom view, I am animating a padding value which is later displaying on Canvas. But other objects like `RectF` are changing its values too. Using kotlin, I have this helper function:

```kotlin
operator fun Pair<Float, Float>.invoke(callback: (Float) -> Unit) {
    with(ValueAnimator.ofFloat(first, second)) {
        duration = 500
        addUpdateListener {
            callback(it.animatedValue as Float)
        }
        start()
    }
}
```

In my Custom View, I have this code:

```kotlin
private val bgCardBounds = RectF(0f, 0f, 0f, 0f)
private var expandedCard = 0
    set(value) {
        field = value
        when (value) {
            1 -> {
                (0f to 32f) {
                    bitmapPadding = it
                    invalidate()
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

On an touch event, when the value of `expandedCard` changes from 0 to 1, then even the values `left`, `top`, `right`, `bottom` values of `bgCardBounds` also changes. Can someone help me point out why this is happening and how to stop it?

Comment: We need to see how you’re using `bgCardBounds` and `bitmapPadding` and how you’re defining `bitmapPadding`.

Comment: are any of the views wrap_content? If you invalidate a wrap_content view after changing its children then its measurements will change.